# PHP not catch exception

Tags: php

I have this code

```
    try
    {
        $a = 1/0;
    }
    catch(Exception $ex)
    {
        echo($ex->getMessage());
    }
```

And when I execute the web page (with Wamp server 2.2). I see [this](http://prntscr.com/3jkphw) and no the text of the exception. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: That's not an exception

Comment: Division by zero is a `warning`, not an `exception`

Comment: See here for list of exceptions in PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php

Comment: And how can I handle errors? Thanks

Comment: @JoséPersichini - in this case, you test the divisor before doing a division, and could throw an exception instead `try
    { $b = 1; $c = 0; if ($c == 0) throw new Exception('Division by zero');
        $a = 1/0;
    }
    catch(Exception $ex)
    {
        echo($ex->getMessage());
    }`

Comment: @JoséPersichini simply don't divide by zero. If it would have been any other language you wouldn't be alive anymore

Comment: Yes, but there isn't an error hanlding like Java, for example?

Comment: @JoséPersichini - suggest you read [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)

Comment: I would generally test if a value is zero before allowing a division to happen in the first place.

Comment: Even in Java, it would be common sense to test for a division by zero situation before executing it

Comment: The division between 0 is only an example. I want to handle other errors

Answer (score 0):

To handle such a case, you need to convert PHP errors to exceptions.  Something along the lines of (PHP 5.3+):

```
set_error_handler(
    function ($code, $mesg) {
        throw new RuntimeException($mesg, $code);
    },
    E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_USER_NOTICE
);

try {
    $a = 1 / 0;
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    die($ex->getMessage());
}
```

(Caveat emptor: not near my terminal, haven't compiled this example.)

If you want to raise different exceptions based on the particular error, then the best you can do is test the message against the patterns you're interested in, and then raise accordingly.

Comment: It works fine, but in which place I have to put the set_error_handler method?

Comment: @JosePersichini: At the beginning of your code, before you start doing anything custom.  So, if you've got index.php which calls a bunch of stuff, put the `set_error_handler` thing at the top of index.php.

Comment: And need I to put this method in all php files with user interface?

Comment: @JosePersichini: That would be one way of going about it (though most frameworks have a single entry point, like index.php).  You could also use [`auto_prepend_file`](http://davidwalsh.name/prepend-append-files-htaccess) to simplify all that work.